# Запятая перед "что" и "как" в роли однородного члена

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

1). Я люблю свежесть утра и (,) когда поют птицы.

2). Сталкиваясь с грубостью, понимаем, как мы ранимы, и (,) что в наших сердцах отзывается каждое слово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Я люблю свежесть утра и когда поют птицы.

2) Сталкиваясь с грубостью, понимаем, как мы ранимы  и что в наших сердцах отзывается каждое слово.

Оба варианта не совсем стандартны, поэтому возникают вопросы о постановке запятых.

В первом случае в однородных отношениях находится  дополнение и придаточное предложение.  Во втором случае однородные придаточные изъяснительные предложения имеют разные союзы, но при этом  союз КАК синонимичен союзу ЧТО.

Answer (score 4):

нет, ни в первом, ни во втором случае запятые не ставятся.

1. я - подлежащее, люблю - сказуемое. люблю что? - свежесть утра и когда поют птицы
2. "мы" - подразумеваемое существительное, понимаем - сказуемое, понимаем что? - как мы ранимы и что в наших сердцах отзывается каждое слово

Comment: А если без "и"? Поставили бы запятую?

1). Я люблю свежесть утра (,) когда поют птицы.

2). Сталкиваясь с грубостью, понимаем, как мы ранимы(,) что в наших сердцах отзывается каждое слово.

Comment: да. Если нет соединительного союза, то запятая ставится

Answer (score 0):

Запятые не нужны. 
Здесь "что" и "как" выступают в роли союзов, присоединяющих придаточные (мотив для запятой), но эти придаточные являются однородными с предшествующим членом предложения и соединены с ним союзом "и". В этом случае запятые не нужны.